# Find Max of Each Value in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of ID values with multiple entries for different dates, How would i go about finding the max date for each ID? Preferably having the answer in a dynamic array as my table of values changes depending on which data the using is parsing

cheers

[image]

Comment: Use `MAXIFS()`. Post data as text table so that we can copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned you wanted it in a dynamic array, so I suggest using `UNIQUE` and `MAXIFS` inside a `LET` and combining the results with the use of `SEQUENCE`.

Something like:

```
=LET(x, UNIQUE(A:A),
mycols, SEQUENCE(1,2),
IF(mycols=1, x,
MAXIFS(B:B, A:A, x)))
```

For example:
[image]

EDIT (a much nicer solution provided by @JvdV): `=CHOOSE({1,2},UNIQUE(A:A),MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,UNIQUE(A:A)))`

Comment: Very tricky answer. I was going to post answer with `FILTERXML()` combine with Let, Unique & Maxifs but your one is more easy and cleaner.

Comment: Another option to get the two columns is `CHOOSE()` which may look (IMO) a little cleaner: `=CHOOSE({1,2},UNIQUE(A:A),MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,UNIQUE(A:A)))`.

Comment: @JvdV nice, going to have to start adding ```CHOOSE``` to my repertoire. Is there a way to make a variable amount of columns so you don't have to hard code something like ```=CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,...,11}...)``` on data that is more extensive?

Comment: @Euler'sDisgracedStepchild. I wish for something like that. Unfortunately there isn't =(